# iSCSI and SERVERS ULTIMATE PRO (android app)

Tags: android, iscsi, ipxe

My questions are always difficult and almost there is nobody to respond with helpful suggestion. This my first post in here. Here's the situation.

I have android phone with SERVERS ULTIMATE PRO application installed. This thing allows iSCSI and TFTP servers. Well my question is.. How to boot to iSCSI from ipxe or gpxe to install some kind of OS and hopefully booting from it..
I reached to the mark where I don't know what is my IQN (there is no option in the servers ultimate application) and I am not very familiar with that LUN target.

Thanks

Comment: I can only set alias to the file storage?

Answer (score 0):

Android is using ulibc library. It is not compatible to glibc. Open-iscsi won't compile at ulibc now. Even user land does not have iSCSI initiator to use. Some people made chroot Debian Linux on top of Android to use iSCSI, that is nothing with Android, my opinion. But I read some mailing list, some people are working on open-iscsi to compile on ulibc. Booting Android from iSCSI will come soon. For now you can boot only Android kernel from network ipxe server, leave the system and data on local disk.

Comment: But if iSCSI is not available for android why did they say they support it as a server option in their app?